# dynamic Link deleted by mistake and have to wait for a month to set it up again

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

**Hello everyone,**
I am new and building my 1st app using Firebase.
I had, previously, added a dynamic link on my domain name in firebase : link.mydomainname.com
It worked fine.
but, by mistake, I deleted it.
I want to set it up again but Firebase tells me

> "Please try again in a month"..

What can I do to make it faster?
Thanks by advance for your help!

Fab

Re-setup the dynamic link domain